# Catch Xpath conditions with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, xpath

I want to catch conditions in a Xpath expression. For example in an expression as below:

```
loan:_applicant/base:_entity/person:_phones/base:SmartRefOfPhoneeJDvviUx[base:_entity/contact:_category/base:_underlyingValue='Personal' and base:_entity/contact:_isMobile/base:_underlyingValue!='true']/base:_entity
```

I want to catch:

```
base:_entity/contact:_category/base:_underlyingValue='Personal'
```

and

```
base:_entity/contact:_isMobile/base:_underlyingValue!='true'
```

The operator **and** in the example Xpath can be **or**

Is it possible to get conditions using Regex?

Comment: The "conditions" are called predicates. Is it possible that you will get XPaths with nested predicates? For example: `/foo[bar[2]='baz']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath predicates are surrounded with square brackets, so

```
string regex=@"\[.*\]";
string predicate=Regex.Match(input, regex).Value;//assuming there is a match
regex=@"\s(and|or)\s";
string[] conditions=Regex.Split(predicate, regex);
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 has functions for regular expression matching, such as matches(), replace(), and tokenize(). These are not available in XPath 1.0.